# Split String in Swift by their capital letters

Tags: arrays, swift, string, split

I want to split an simple String by their capital letters into an array. It should look something like this:

```
let teststring = "NaCuHHe"
```

and the result should be:

```
["Na", "Cu", "H", "He"]
```

I tried the following:

```
func capitalLetters(s: String) -> [Character] {
    return s.characters.filter { ("A"..."Z").contains($0) }
}
```

I searched trough the documentation and other websites but i did not find any helpful things. Im at the end. I don't know what to do more hence im really new to swift. It still gives me only the capital ones and i don't know how to change that it gives me the things behind de capital one as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*(Swift 3)*

We could let ourselves be inspired by the implementation of the [`split` function in `Sequence`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift), and implement our own `splitBefore` method (split before separator, omitting empty subsequences), that keep the separators in the splitted sequence.

```
extension Sequence {
    func splitBefore(
        separator isSeparator: (Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool
    ) rethrows -> [AnySequence<Iterator.Element>] {
        var result: [AnySequence<Iterator.Element>] = []
        var subSequence: [Iterator.Element] = []

        var iterator = self.makeIterator()
        while let element = iterator.next() {
            if try isSeparator(element) {
                if !subSequence.isEmpty {
                    result.append(AnySequence(subSequence))
                }
                subSequence = [element]
            }
            else {
                subSequence.append(element)
            }
        }
        result.append(AnySequence(subSequence))
        return result
    }
}
```

Used as follows

```
/* help property */
extension Character {
    var isUpperCase: Bool { return String(self) == String(self).uppercased() }
}

/* example usage */  
let teststring = "NaCuHHe"
let splitted = teststring
    .characters
    .splitBefore(separator: { $0.isUpperCase })
    .map{String($0)}
print(splitted) // ["Na", "Cu", "H", "He"]
```

Comment: Works beautifully but i had to change .splitBefore(separator: { $0.isUpperCase }) to .splitBefore(whereSeparator: { $0.isUpperCase }) to actually get it working

Comment: @user3043098 A early-copy (from my code) mistake on my behalf, should be `separator`. `Sequence` extension updated (name of first external parameter name now `separator`, not `whereSeparator`).

Comment: @dfri insane how much code this "small" problem needs. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3043098 happy to help. Note that we can perform the same task with "less amount of code", but it will probably come at the cost of semantic complexity, hence a reason why the Swift stdlibs are sometimes somewhat verbose. E.g. [simpleBob's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39594037/4573247) could be used to construct a `String` extension that would be (less general and) more compact.

Answer (score 6):

A different solution in Functional Programming style

### isUppercase

First of all lets define an easy method to check whether a Character is uppercase

```
extension Character {
    var isUppercase: Bool { return String(self).uppercased() == String(self) }
}
```

### Indexes

Next we need the indexes of the uppercase characters

```
let indexes = Set(text
    .characters
    .enumerated()
    .filter { $0.element.isUppercase }
    .map { $0.offset })
```

### Building the result

Now we can build the result

```
let chunks = text
    .characters
    .map { String($0) }
    .enumerated()
    .reduce([String]()) { chunks, elm -> [String] in
        guard !chunks.isEmpty else { return [elm.element] }
        guard !indexes.contains(elm.offset) else { return chunks + [String(elm.element)] }

        var chunks = chunks
        chunks[chunks.count-1] += String(elm.element)
        return chunks
    }
```

### Output

```
["Na", "Cu", "H", "He"]
```

Comment: Another neat solution! But note that there's a danger in the explicit access by index (`chunks[chunks.count-1]`) in case the first character in `text` is lower cased (say `"aAa"`): in which case `chunks.count` in `chunks[chunks.count-1]` will, at first pass, evaluate to `0`, an hence a runtime exception when attempting to access `chunks[-1]`. Easily fixed with a conditional, however :) (also, note that OP use property name `teststring` rather than `text`, so you might want to write out the latter in your answer, for clarity, e.g. `let text = "NaCuHHe"`).

Comment: @appzYourLife  very nice explaination. Helped me a lot to understand the code very well hence im very new to swift !

Answer (score 5):

Using Regex -

```
func splitYourString(_ s: String) ->[String] {
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([a-z]*)([A-Z])") //<-Use capturing, `([a-z]*)`->$1, `([A-Z])`->$2
return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: s, range: NSRange(0..<s.utf16.count),
                                      withTemplate: "$1 $2").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) .components(separatedBy: " ")
}
print(splitYourString("NaCuHHe"))     //["Na", "Cu", "H", "He"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be:

```
let input = "NaCuHHe"

var result = [String]()
var lastIndex = 0
for (index, letter) in input.characters.enumerate() where String(letter) != String(letter).lowercaseString {
    guard index != lastIndex else { continue }
    result += [input.substringWithRange(input.startIndex.advancedBy(lastIndex) ..< input.startIndex.advancedBy(index))]
    lastIndex = index
}
result += [input.substringWithRange(input.startIndex.advancedBy(lastIndex) ..< input.endIndex)]
```

result is `["Na", "Cu", "H", "He"]`

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but here's a straightforward Swift 3 approach using whitespace-delimiting. Might not be as elegant as the functional or iterator approaches, but it doesn't involve making any custom extensions on existing classes.

```
    let originalString = "NaCuHHe"
    var newStringArray: [String] = []
    for character in originalString.characters {
        if String(character) == String(character).uppercased() {
            newStringArray.append(" ")
        }
        newStringArray.append(String(character))
    }

    let newString = newStringArray.joined().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).components(separatedBy: " ")
    print(newString) // Returns ["Na", "Cu", "H", "He"]
```

Answer (score 2):

dfri's answer which is great modified for Swift 4

his Sequence extension is the same, but extensions for as used are different:

```
    extension Sequence {
    func splitBefore(
        separator isSeparator: (Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool
    ) rethrows -> [AnySequence<Iterator.Element>] {
        var result: [AnySequence<Iterator.Element>] = []
        var subSequence: [Iterator.Element] = []

        var iterator = self.makeIterator()
        while let element = iterator.next() {
            if try isSeparator(element) {
                if !subSequence.isEmpty {
                    result.append(AnySequence(subSequence))
                }
                subSequence = [element]
            }
            else {
                subSequence.append(element)
            }
        }
        result.append(AnySequence(subSequence))
        return result
    }
}
```

string extension for use:

```
extension String {

var isLowercase: Bool {
    return self == self.lowercased()
}

var isUppercase: Bool {
    return self == self.uppercased()
}
```

and then used as follows since characters has been deprecated is Swift 4

```
    let teststring = "NaCuHHe"
    let splitted = teststring
    .splitBefore(separator: { $0.isUppercase })
    .map{String($0)}
    print(splitted) // ["Na", "Cu", "H", "He"]
```

Comment: probably should be `String($0).isUppercase`

Answer (score 0):

Answer in Swift 4

Another approach is popping the last word (which starts with capital case) to the result list until there is no more capital character is found in the given string.

```
extension String {
    func splitWord() -> [String] {
        var result = [String]()
        var temp = self
        var done = false
        while !done {
            if let index = temp.lastIndex(where: { $0.isUppercase }) {
                result.insert(String(temp[index...]), at: 0)
                temp = String(temp[..<index])
                done = temp.distance(from: temp.startIndex, to: index) == 0
            }
            else {
                result.insert(temp, at: 0)
                done = true
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer in Swift 5.

Inspired from Apple implementation for split, [split function in Collection](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift).

What i did is to change how index for subsequences are created.

In original implementation, when you hit a separator:

1. add a new subsequence to the array of subsequences
2. form a new index after the separator
3. attribute that index to next subsequence start

in my implementation:

1. add a new subsequence to the array of subsequences
2. attribute current index to next subsequence start
3. form a new index after the separator

   ```
   extension Collection {
   @inlinable
   public __consuming func split(
       maxSplits: Int = Int.max,
       omittingEmptySubsequences: Bool = true,
       includeSeparator: Bool = false,
       whereSeparator isSeparator: (Element) throws -> Bool
   ) rethrows -> [SubSequence] {
       var result: [SubSequence] = []
       var subSequenceStart: Index = startIndex

       func appendSubsequence(end: Index) -> Bool {
           if subSequenceStart == end && omittingEmptySubsequences {
               return false
           }
           result.append(self[subSequenceStart..<end])
           return true
       }

       if maxSplits == 0 || isEmpty {
           _ = appendSubsequence(end: endIndex)
           return result
       }

       var subSequenceEnd = subSequenceStart
       let cachedEndIndex = endIndex
       while subSequenceEnd != cachedEndIndex {
           if try isSeparator(self[subSequenceEnd]) {
               let didAppend = appendSubsequence(end: subSequenceEnd)
               if includeSeparator {
                   subSequenceStart = subSequenceEnd
                   formIndex(after: &subSequenceEnd)
               } else {
                   formIndex(after: &subSequenceEnd)
                   subSequenceStart = subSequenceEnd
               }

               if didAppend && result.count == maxSplits {
                   break
               }
               continue
           }
           formIndex(after: &subSequenceEnd)
       }

       if subSequenceStart != cachedEndIndex || !omittingEmptySubsequences {
           result.append(self[subSequenceStart..<cachedEndIndex])
       }

       return result
   }
   ```

   The result of test is:

   ```
      let splitedString = "NaCuHHe".split(includeSeparator: true, whereSeparator: { $0.isUppercase })
      print(splitedString) // ["Na", "Cu", "H", "He"]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.map({ $0.isUppercase ? " \($0)" : "\($0)" }).joined().split(separator: " ")
```